# POSIX Thread Stack Memory - Can we have varying stack sizes and the safety issues?

Tags: multithreading, stack, pthreads

I have couple questions regarding the POSIX thread stack size and their safety issues:

A) Can we have varying stack sizes (for each thread set using: **pthread_attr_getstacksize**)?

B) When a thread dies (detached/exited), will the operating system reclaim its memory pages?

C) Could a thread keep writing into another threads stack segment if they happen to be adjacent to each other on the virtual memory mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) Yes, of course, that's the purpose of `pthread_attr_setstacksize`.

B) Yes, calling `pthread_detach` or `pthread_join` causes the thread resources to be reclaimed upon termination.

C) Theoretically yes, but since on most systems the stack grows backwards (from high to low address), you'd have to do some kind of buffer overflow in order to get out of your current stack space.